# How can I use bash to parse out only a section of a variable with different delimiters?

Tags: bash

I have a loop in a bash file to show me all of the files in a directory, each as its own variable.  I need to take that variable (filename) and parse out only a section of it.

Example:

92378478234978ehbWHATIWANT#98712398712398723

Now, assuming "ehb" and the pound symbol never change, how can I just capture WHATIWANT into its own variable?

---

So far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILENAME in `dir -d *` ; do

done
```

---

Comment: As a comment: it would probably be better to write `for FILENAME in *; do ...; done` -- `dir -d *` seems superfluous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sed` to edit out the parts you don't want.

```
want=$(echo "$FILENAME" | sed -e 's/.*ehb\(.*\)#.*/\1/')
```

Or you can use Bash's parameter expansion to strip out the tail and head.

```
want=${FILENAME%#*}; want=${want#*ehb}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
for i in '92378478234978ehbWHATIWANT#98712398712398723' ; do
    j=$(echo $i | sed -e 's/^.*ehb//' -e 's/#.*$//')
    echo $j
done
```

produces:

```
WHATIWANT
```

Answer (score 0):

using only the bash shell, no need external tools

```
$ string=92378478234978ehbWHATIWANT#98712398712398723
$ echo ${string#*ehb}
WHATIWANT#98712398712398723
$ string=${string#*ehb}
$ echo ${string%#*}
WHATIWANT
```